# How to create trigger to change record after update?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I have a problem with trigger. I have simple table `stats`. In this table I have for example: `id`, `energy`, `is_alive`. I need create a trigger `ON UPDATE` something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER AFTER UPDATE
IF energy <= 0 THEN 
  UPDATE stats SET is_alive = false
```

and when I execute:

```
UPDATE stats SET energy = -3 WHERE id = 7
```

I would like:

1. update value on - 3
2. execute trigger and check is new value is <= 0
3. if yes update is_alive = false on this record id = 7

Is this possible? Or does the trigger have to check all table and change all 
rows when `energy` will be `<= 0`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A trigger function like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION trg_stats_insup_bef()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$func$
BEGIN
IF NEW.energy <= 0 THEN
   NEW.is_alive := FALSE;
END IF;
RETURN NEW;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And a [trigger](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtrigger.html) (`BEFORE`, *not* `AFTER`):

```
CREATE TRIGGER insup_bef
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF energy ON stats  -- covers INSERT, too
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_stats_insup_bef()
```